# SSIS - Manipulate the list of comma separated values in a user variable

Tags: arrays, ssis

I have user variable of type string(MyNames) which contains a list of comma separate values. I have a conditional splits which outputs around 96 names. In the next step, I only want to put only those names in a Recordset Destination which match with the names in the comma separated list string variable MyNames. The Recordset Destination is a uservariable of type Object.

I am new to SSIS and I dont have any scripting experience. Your help will be appreciated. Thank You

Comment: how do you set the variable value ?

Comment: Currently, just passing a comma separated list in the Value section of the Variables like
John, Ali, Peter, William

Comment: One solution I would recommend is to use a table wherein you store all the names and then do a lookup operation with it instead of using a variable. Is that possible for you ?

Comment: The problem is that I dont have write access to the DB to create a table. I can just read from it. So, I can not store the values in a table

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lookup transformation with full cache (it will require storing the list of names first)
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattm/2008/10/18/lookup-cache-modes/
Depending on the comma separated values source, I can give you more alternatives.